# gnuplot auto sorts times

Tags: linux, charts, gnuplot

i have a file which looks as follows:

```
19:40:47,2772
19:41:50,2896
19:42:50,2870
19:43:51,2851
19:44:53,2824
19:45:55,2891
.
.
.
07:52:53,2772
07:53:56,2767
07:55:00,2709
07:56:01,2713
07:57:04,2844
07:58:04,2750
07:59:05,2744
08:00:08,2812
08:01:11,2728
08:02:14,2852
```

and im trying to do the simple task of making a graph with time X axis & number Y axis.

code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

unset multiplot
set xdata time
set datafile separator ","

set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"



set title "defect number"

set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"

plot "Defect_number_03-03-16_08.04.49.csv" using 1:2 w lines
pause -1
```

problem is that gnuplot autosorts the time and my chart looks like this:

[image: example]

I want to make a chart according to the order in the file, any help will be great =)

Comment: try `plot "data.csv" u 0:2:xtic(1)`.

Comment: almost 3 years later, the same question came up. you may want to check and adapt this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031572/how-do-i-get-gnuplot-to-read-my-time-format-and-keep-the-times-in-order-of-the-i/54045012#54045012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give the plot command

```
plot datafile u 1:2
```

you are telling gnuplot that the first column is your x-value and the second is your y-value.  Naturally, earlier times are further to the left (as you didn't post your full data, I have used only the part you did post - this will cause a "skip" in the axis labels).

[image]

You can use a pseudocolumn to use the line number as your x-value.  The **0** column corresponds to the line number (see `help pseudocolumns`).

Thus `plot datafile u 0:2` will use the line number as the x-coordinate and the 2nd column as the y-coordinate.

[image]

We still need to add the correct x-axis labels, and can't rely on them to be generated correctly in this case.  We would use the `xtic` function to do this, as<sup>**1**</sup>

```
plot datafile u 0:2:xtic(1)
```

[image]

which tells gnuplot to use the value in column 1 as an xtic, but it will read this literally and not format it as you have desired with the time.  To do this, we can manually cast this to the correct string

```
plot datafile u 0:2:xtic(strftime("%H:%M",strptime("%H:%M:%S",strcol(1)))) w lines
```

[image]

Here, the `strcol` function reads column 1 as a string, the `strptime` function turns this into the internal time representation using the specified format string for reading it, and finally the `strftime` formats this as time string using the specified output string.

---

As Christoph stated in his answer, these solutions will cause uniform spacing of the points.  If the points are already uniform spaced, this is not a problem, and if the points are very close to uniform spaced, it is probably acceptable as well (it looks like your points are about 1 minute apart give or take a couple of seconds).

However, if we want the absolutely correct spacing, we will need to add a date to the lines.  This could be done in the original data file during the creation, or we could use an external process to add the dates only when needed leaving the original file exactly the same.

As you are only marking off the time and not the day in your tic marks, the actual day doesn't matter.  It only matters that the times from the next morning are in the next day from the times from the last night.

We can use an external program to add dates.  The following python 3 program reads the data file and adds a date to it (using Jan 1st, 2015 for the first date - as previously mentioned this date doesn't really matter).  If a time occurs earlier in the day from the previous one, it moves to the next day.  Here is the program **adddates.py**:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from sys import argv

last = None
offset = timedelta(days=0)
for x in open(argv[1],"r"):
    vals = x.split(",")
    dte = datetime.strptime("01/01/2015 "+vals[0],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") + offset
    if last!=None and last>dte:
        offset+= timedelta(days=1)
        dte = dte + offset
    last = dte
    print(dte.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),vals[1],sep=",",end="")
```

The output from running this on the data file looks like:

```
2015-01-01 19:40:47,2772
2015-01-01 19:41:50,2896
2015-01-01 19:42:50,2870
2015-01-01 19:43:51,2851
2015-01-01 19:44:53,2824
2015-01-01 19:45:55,2891
...
2015-01-02 07:52:53,2772
2015-01-02 07:53:56,2767
...
```

We can now read data from this program by opening a pipe in our plot command.

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
plot "< adddates.py datafile" u 1:2 with lines
```

[image]

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Note that this also causes labels to overlap, as it uses all of them.  To use every other one, we could have used `xtic(int($0) % 2 == 0 ? strcol(1):"")`.  A similar technique can be used with the format using the correct labels as well.

Comment: wow, great answer, ill look into using $0,
otherwise as you both suggested - will reformat the data to include the full date format.

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A proper solution is to save your data with full date and time, or as timestamps. 
All other solutions with `$0` and labelling the xtics with `xticlabel` requires your data to be spaces equidistantly, which doesn't seem to be the case.

So, just save your data as e.g. UNIX timestamp and you can use all nice gnuplot features without fiddling.